# Supabase session not saved with React Native after cold-start

Tags: react-native, expo, supabase

I have an issue regarding supabase sessions after cold-starting the app.
Everytime I force quit the app on the phone, its asking me to sign in again.

Here is my API.js

```
export const api = createClient(API_URL, API_KEY, { auth: { storage: AsyncStorage, autoRefreshToken: true, persistSession: true, detectSessionInUrl: false, }, });
```

and everytime I open the app inside App.js it has a useEffect hook with this function to get the session

```
export async function verifySession(setState) {
const { data, error } = await api.auth.getSession();

setState(data.session);
}
```

plus another function to handle the authStateChange inside the same useEffect

```
api.auth.onAuthStateChange(async (event, session) => { console.log(auth event fired ${event}); setSession(session); });
```

So I don't understand why the session isnt stored even when I'm cold-starting the app.
Any toughts?

I'm trying to make the app retrieve session after cold-starting it for the user not having to log-in again and again.

Comment: Hey Menash,

Supabase engineer here - thanks for your query! Did you manage to figure this out? Let us know!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? backgrounding and foregrounding my app constantly logs me out

Comment: I had to add a state "isLoggedIn" and did a useEffect like this:

`useEffect(() => {
  verifySession(setSession);

  if (session !== null && session !== undefined) {
    setLoggedIn(true);
  } else {
    setLoggedIn(false);
  }

  api.auth.onAuthStateChange((_event, session) => {
    if (session !== null && session !== undefined) {
      setLoggedIn(true);
    } else {
      setLoggedIn(false);
    }
    setSession(session);
    verifySubscription(setSubscription, session?.user?.id);
  });
}, [session]);`